# Invoking "cmake" failed

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have created a workspace and inside the src, i cloned the following

https://github.com/viirya/ros-driver-techman-robot.git

and sourced the workspace and tried making catkin_make. and i am getting the following error

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'tm_hardware_interface' but neither
  'tm_hardware_interface_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor 'tm_hardware_interface_LIBRARIES'
  is defined.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  ros-driver-techman-robot/tm_driver/CMakeLists.txt:123 (catkin_package)

-- +++ processing catkin package: 'tm700_moveit_config'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros-driver-techman-robot/tm700_moveit_config)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'tm900_moveit_config'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros-driver-techman-robot/tm900_moveit_config)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'usb_camera_test'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros-driver-techman-robot/usb_camera_test)
-- Could NOT find usb_cam (missing: usb_cam_DIR)

-- Could not find the required component 'usb_cam'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "usb_cam" with any
  of the following names:

    usb_camConfig.cmake
    usb_cam-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "usb_cam" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "usb_cam_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "usb_cam" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  ros-driver-techman-robot/usb_camera_test/CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

i am using ros melodic on ubuntu 18.04.

See also "/home/akash/project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/akash/project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381254/invoking-%22cmake%22-failed/) by [akash12124234](https://answers.ros.org/users/76117/akash12124234/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2021-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

there are missing dependencies. `usb_cam` [is released for melodic](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_melodic_default.html?q=usb_cam) so install it using apt. there is [nothing released starting](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_melodic_default.html?q=tm_) with `tm_`, so you need the `tm_hardware_interface` package from source (wherever you can get that from).

Note that the repo you clone is quite stale (~2years old). You could ask for help there. Especially as `tm_hardware_interface` is [declared as a system dependency](https://github.com/viirya/ros-driver-techman-robot/blob/5e20a589ae5347e953db9392dcb2281d8aec3813/tm_driver/CMakeLists.txt#L134). This is probably a mistake or you'll get some proprietary library with your techman robot.

Anyways, I suggest to use the official [Techman Repos](https://github.com/TechmanRobotInc?type=source), as long as there is no very specific need to use the other. This is also officially supported on Melodic and up-to-date...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2021-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akash12124234](https://answers.ros.org/users/76117/akash12124234/) on 2021-06-28**:
the suggested techman works perfect